# Sencha Touch - Range Slider?

Tags: slider, range, sencha-touch

is it anyhow possible to have 2 handles on sencha touch slider, so that I can select a range of values? Or is there any other way I can achieve this without a slider? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is available in sencha 2.0.0 . All you have to put two values inside value field.
ie

```
{
     xtype:'sliderfield',
     values:[value1,value2]
}
```